# Setup of the Divio CMS Repositories

Tags: python, django, divio

The Divio Django CMS offers two servers: TEST and LIVE. Are these also two separate repositories? Or how is this done in the background?

I'm wondering because I would have the feeling the LIVE server is its own repository that just pulls from the TEST whenever I press deploy. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

All Divio projects (django CMS, Python, PHP, whatever) have a Live and Test environment.

By default, both build the project from its repository's `master` branch (in older projects, `develop`).

On request, *custom tracking branches* can be enabled, so that the Live and Test environments will build from separate branches.

When a build successfully completes, the Docker image can be reused until changes are made to the project's repository. This means that after a successful deployment on Test, the Docker image doesn't need to be rebuilt, and the Live environment can be deployed much faster from the pre-built image. (Obviously this is only possible when they are on the same branch.)

Comment: OK, so are LIVE and TEST two separate repositories? My understanding is, that LIVE pulls from TEST master-branch as a one-way operation. Such that the TEST master branch is the single source of truth. Or is this not how it is?

Comment: No no, the project only has one repository. The live and test environments don't make pull commands. They just build the project from whichever branch (usually both `master`) they are configured to work with.

Comment: Aha, ok. I guess then they're both containers. And LIVE only builds when you press "deploy" on the TEST environment?